# How to change background image with post thumbnail function WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm Creating a WordPress Theme. And i have a section with the background image property in my CSS. Example

My HTML

```
 <div class="header"></div>
```

My CSS

```
.header{
   background-image:url('../path/images/image.jpg');
}
```

Now I want to make this section Dynamic. so the user can change their background image. 
Now i was trying to use `post_thumbnail()` function to change my images.But i find out, that we can use that for `<img/>` tag only.

Is there any way or function in wordpress that we can use to change the background image?

Comment: If it's for the css why not try inline style

Comment: yes for having background dynamically we have to style inline. Check below for the code. I have answered it. @daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try this. It worked for me. :)

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>

<div class="header" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in css, you have to write in php page or template.

Please see below code:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>)" class="header"></div>
```

Here, '$post->ID' is the ID of the post/page.

I hope, this will help you.